# Prove a complex inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to prove that 
\begin{gather*}
| z^4 + z + 1 | \geq |z^4| - |z| -1
\end{gather*}
with $z = (r\exp (it))$ and $r \geq 2^\frac{1}{3}$

It seems like I only have to use the reversed triangle inequality, then it will be very easy. But it is explicitly given that $r \geq 2^\frac{1}{3}$. Is this inequality untrue when  $r\leq 2^\frac{1}{3}$? I lack intution here.

Answer (score 1):

It is true in general:
$$
|z^4|=|z^4+z+1-z-1|\leq|z^4+z+1|+|-z|+|-1|=|z^4+z+1|+|z|+1.
$$
Perhaps, the other information is relevant for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Using triangle inequality i.e.
$$|a|-|b|\leq |a+b|$$
In this case when you apply this inequality it yields
$$|z^4+z+1|\geq |z^4+z|-|1|\geq |z^4|-|z|-|1|=|z|^4-|z|-1$$